# How can I get the desired results from the Sakila database using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to: Find the movies whose total number of actors is above the average. Return the movie names and its number of actors ordered by the title. IMPORTANT NOTE: this query should return many movies. Show only the top 10 results.

I am using mySQL workbench for this, and performing the query on the Sakila database.

[picture attached]

[image: 1]

My code so far is:

```
SELECT film.title, COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) AS actor_count
FROM film_actor
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id=film.film_id
GROUP BY film.film_id
HAVING COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) >
AVG(film_actor.actor_id)
ORDER BY film.title
```

Comment: For one thing, don't use `AVG(film_actor.actor_id)`. This will give you the average of the IDs of the actor entities, not the average count of actors per movie

Comment: The [sakila db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html) is available  for download here: [Other MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html)  (just for anyone who need to know where to find it)

Comment: Where is the `[` in your query coming from  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
SELECT film.film_id,film.title, COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) AS actor_count
FROM film_actor
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id=film.film_id
GROUP BY film.film_id,film.title
)
select cte.title,cte.actor_count from 
cte where cte.actor_count>(select avg(actor_count) from cte)
order by cte.title limit 0,10
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[SELECT film.film_id,film.title, COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) AS actor_count
FROM ' at line 2

Comment: And, with the `[` removed it is not returning the top 10. but the first 10 on alphabetic order of title name.....

Comment: @Luuk what you assume in top 10 result because according to the question it want only top 10 result order by movie name.

Comment: Ok, I must have overlooked that, because it's a bit strange to return the top 10 order by name of movies having more than the average count of actors...... In fact the question sound like homework .....